# Accessing symbolic links in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, symbolic-link

How can you access files in folders that are links, on a shared folder in VirtualBox?

For instance, I've got a folder named

`/home/mrlister/misc`

on my host computer, which is shared as `/media/sf_misc` in my (Linux) VB guest OS. Now I can read the files in `/media/sf_misc/` just fine, but I've also got a link in there, `docs`, that points to `/home/mrlister/Documents`.
And the problem is, when I try to access `/media/sf_misc/docs` I get an error saying

> This link cannot be used, because its target "/home/mrlister/Documents" doesn't exist.

Now under other circumstances, I'd conclude that it's simply impossible for programs in the VB to gain access to linked material that I haven't shared explicitly in the settings.
However, I have another virtual computer, which is running Windowx XP, and that one can access said link in the same shared folder just fine! That is, it can look at `file://///VBOXSVR/misc/docs` and not try to follow the link, it just treats `docs` as an ordinary directory.

So, what do I have to do in order to achieve the same functionality on a virtual Linux machine? I'm not sure what to try.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that Windows guest is seeing the Link as a folder, whereas your Linux guest is seeing the link as a link to /home/mrlister/Documents **ON THE LOCAL FILESYSTEM inside the guest**, which doesn't exist of course. I hope I explain myself

Comment: That's a possible explanation. But is there a solution?

Comment: Well, trawling the virtualbox forums leads mostly to discussion of the problems with **creating** links on shared folders, apart from that in the past, accessing symlinks failed also on windows guests, and that was "fixed". I can't find a discussion of a samba style "follow symlinks" option. 
What happens with a hard link?
If the problem is in fact as you have defined it, and not an example you wrote to describe something else, then what about a simple workaround?
Out of interest, how does a hardlink behave?

Comment: Not to start a discussion here, but I can confirm the same behaviour on a windows host with windows and linux guests. With a windows guest the link is followed host side and with a linux guest the link is resolved guest side. https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10085#comment:7 has some clarification. You might do best to bring this up on the virtualbox forums and once you have researched everything there, possibly open a ticket, but read https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Bugtracker first. I am going to answer your question.

Comment: OK, I'll dive into that. As to your question if a hard link works: yes, but only with normal files, not with folders. So I'd have to make links to all the files in the desired folder, and add new links as I create new files. No, then I'd be better off turning it into a new shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is it cannot be done, not with the current version of VirtualBox anyway.
Please see my comments on your question for more details.

Comment: `VBoxManage setextradata VM_NAME VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/SHARE_NAME 1` ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking [has been solved here](https://superuser.com/a/1656312/292060).

Create (on the **guest**) `/etc/modprobe.d/vboxsf.conf` with this line:

```
options vboxsf follow_symlinks=1
```